# JButton call method on click

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have an array of buttons and when I click on a button this button should call a method with his position in the array.

```
class MyActionLauncher implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){

        for(int i = 1; i!= z; i++){
            for(int o = 1; i != s; o++){
                if(ae.getSource() == buttons[i][o] ){
                    ClassX.turn(i, o);
                }
            }
        }


    }
}
```

How to do this?

Comment: Seed the value in the `actionCommand` property or the `clientProperty` property. Given the event `source` you could also calculate its position in the array/grid

Comment: Your termination conditions of the for loops seem really strange. You should re-think these.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the actionPerformed(event e) of each button of your array. Seems boring, but your declaration will be like this :

```
JButton [][] buttons = new JButton[10][10]();
for(int i = 0;i<10;++i){
    for(int j = 0;j<10;++j){
        buttons[i][j].addActionListener(new ButtonListener{

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
               //my action
            }
        });
     }
}
```

Hope it helps